# How to print the Error Message from Nuance

Tags: objective-c, speech-to-text, nuance

I am developing an voice app using Nuance Speechkit .I wan to print the error message from nuance .I dont know how to get the error message.

This is the delegate method

```
- (void)transaction:(SKTransaction *)transaction didFailWithError:(NSError *)error suggestion:(NSString *)suggestion
{
}
```

And This is the error i am getting in console.

**NMT CloudRecognizer Error [Session ID:d40874d7-e31c-43bd-b268-0792c1b26def] [Type:2] [Code:5] [Message:(null)] [ErrorParam:AUDIO_INFO] [Prompt:Sorry, speech not recognized. Please try again.]
2017-07-07 12:19:46.297803 Link[3223:2004075] CloudRecognizer Error [Session ID:d40874d7-e31c-43bd-b268-0792c1b26def] [Type:2] [Code:5] [Message:(null)] [ErrorParam:AUDIO_INFO] [Prompt:Sorry, speech not recognized. Please try again.**

I want to get the prompt and need to show a popup .How can i do this .Please help me .

Comment: If you want just pop up the error message, the simple way is to use UIAlertController

Comment: @Khokim Mamarasulov ,I know how to popup the UIAlertController ,I dont know  to how the promt :Sorry ,Speech not recognized.Please try again later.

Comment: what is printed when you log error, or suggestion in this delegate ?

Comment: @Khokim Mamarasulov ,if i log the error i am getting Errrr:Cloud transaction reported an error. and if i log the suggestion i am getting (null) only.